# ASP-Net MVC5 Crystal Reports: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReports/P_Order.rpt"));
TableLogOnInfo logon = new TableLogOnInfo();
logon = rpt.Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo;
logon.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = myServerName";
logon.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "myDBname";
logon.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "myUserID";
logon.ConnectionInfo.Password = "myPassword";
rpt.Database.Tables[0].ApplyLogOnInfo(logon);
Stream stream = rpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
return File(stream, "application/pdf");
```

Error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The system cannot find the path specified. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The system cannot find the path specified.

Source Error: 



Line 102:            rpt.Database.Tables[0].ApplyLogOnInfo(logon);
Line 103:
Line 104:            Stream stream = rpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
Line 105:            return File(stream, "application/pdf");
Line 106:       


Stack Trace: 



[COMException (0x80004005): The system cannot find the path specified.
]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext) +0
   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext) +1140
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext) +655
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportOptions options) +111
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType formatType) +98
   Procurement.Controllers.ReportsController.OrderReport(DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate, Int32 DepartmentId, Int32 SiteId, Boolean Delivered) in c:\Users\Abdalla\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Procurement\Procurement\Controllers\ReportsController.cs:104
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +309
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9657896
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. But the problem doesn't appear if the report have no parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

1. Hmmm. I use backslashes - not forward slashes.
2. In Visual Studio, make sure your crystal report's Build Action is set to "Content" and "Copy to Output Directory" is set to "Copy Always"
3. Troubleshoot this way:

.

```
string xxx = rpt.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\CrystalReports\P_Order.rpt"));

//then log the value of 'xxx' somewhere, just to make sure the path is what you are expecting it to be
//then verify on the server that the folder and report do in fact exist at the location specified by 'xxx'
```

Comment: Build action should be set to `Embedded Resource` not `Content`