# Trouble in finding "Copy to Output Directory" option in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

when I am trying to export my report to my local folder with below code crystalReport.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"C:\ASD.pdf");

I got this error

> The system cannot find the path specified.

trying to fix this as suggest by other users but can't find this option

> "Copy to Output Directory".

Comment: waiting for answers..

Comment: Try exporting it to the desktop, 
`string desktopLocation = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            string fileName = "ASD.pdf";
            System.IO.Path.Combine(desktopLocation, fileName);`

Comment: also do you have it set to `always copy to directory` or something like that within the `Solution explorer`?

Comment: I didn't got any error but nothing was exported to my desktop. where can I find the option copy to directory option??

Comment: In order to access the `Copy to Output Directory` Follow these steps.
1st - Open `Solution Explorer`2nd - Highlight (single right click on the current form, in my case it is `Form1.cs`3rd - Press `F4` this should bring up the properties of the `Form1.cs file`4th - Change `Copy to Output Directory : Do not copy` to `Copy to Output Directory : Always Copy`

Answer (score 1):

That error might be returned under [various circumstances](https://www.arcanadev.com/support/kb/K00000483.aspx), but I'd recommend to check if ASP.NET has write access to C:\ (which is usually not the case) and change the output directory. If it will not help, see [similar topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794396/crystal-report-cannot-find-the-path-specified-in-windows-server-2008-using-mv) before asking same questions again.